# How should I interpret the request object in node.js express callbacks?

Tags: node.js, express, documentation, request

The node.js express module router callbacks receive a request and response object.  Dumping the request object is gigantic, so it's pretty tough to interpret where the data I want to read is and how to interpret other properties of the object.

The [router documentation](http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html) doesn't mention anything about how to interpret the request object.  Is there any documentation anywhere that is less obvious or a different spec that the object conforms to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the [API Request documentation](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req).  The [API documentation](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html) is fairly thorough if you have any trouble with express.

Comment: I thought I looked a lot harder in the docs and didn't run into that.  Though I suppose it doesn't help that the router documentation doesn't link to it.  Thanks.

Comment: @JoeyCarson The organization of that site is a bit confusing. You were in the guide; the [Router docs are here](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router).

Answer (score 1):

What data are you looking for exactly? If, for instance, you need incoming form data, it'll be in the request body i.e. req.body or if you're looking for a header, it'll be in req.headers.